# Android ListView only shows data after app restart

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to fill a list view with data i'm receiving from and odata service in json format. The data is already fetched and can be accessed with `getIODataEntry()`.

I'm appending the respective values to a string to see an output in LogCat and split the string afterwards to fill my listView with the single values.

```
ListView listView_CarrierCollection = null;
...

private void showData() {

    Log.d("debug", "log 1");

    String carrierCollection = "";

    for(int i=0; i<getIODataEntry().size(); i++) {
        carrierCollection += getIODataEntry().get(i).getPropertyValue("Carrname");
        carrierCollection += ";";
    }

    Log.d("debug", carrierCollection);

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(carrierCollection.split(";")));
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_textview, list);
    listView_CarrierCollection.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    Log.d("debug", "log 2");
}
```

everything works, but only after my devices' screen has turned off and has being turned on again or after i close and reopen the app. The logs instead are prompted instantly to logcat, but the listView only contains the data after reopening the app.

Am i missing something out? Every hint would be appreciated!

EDIT: 
Finally got it to work - turned out it had nothing to do with the posted code above. I had some listeners, that were trying to update a TextField in a Fragment. It seems as if `MyFragment.textfield.setText("test");` blocked any further operations in some way. Surrounding it with `runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){ ... })` solved it for me and got the whole thing to work.

Nevertheless thank you for your ideas and help!

Comment: Do the logs show up in the first time, or are they only shown later like the list? when do you call `showData()`?

Comment: The logs are showing up the first time, but not the list. After reopening the app the list is shown, but not the logs. When clicking a button first a method `getData()` is called and shortly after that `showData()`

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what's the issue without looking at the activity code - you might be doing something in onPause on onResume that changes the visibility of the list. Can you post the Activity code and the xml layout?

Answer (score 0):

*Late to the party but may help someone else in the future*

In my case, I wasn't calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` when i was updating my mutable array list. Therefore it was only working when i was tuning sceen off and on again. But after calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` it worked as usual.

Hope it helps ;)